# Two Producers send data simultaneously

Tags: java

I have a producer sending data for 15 seconds. I just replicate the same program and run it from different window while the first producer is already running. I get "Port 3333 already in use, java.net.BindException: Address already in use"

How can I make multiple producers (multi-process not threaded) send data at the same socket? However I dont know from where the port 3333 comes into picture.

What might be wrong with my program? I can provide the complete problem statement if desired. However in short I am using custom Kafka Producer to send data and I want two such Kafka Producers to send data.

Comment: Where is the process that receive the data? Listening on the port 3333, maybe?

Comment: Can you provide the source for Consumer and Producer? This will allow us to provide you with proper solution. My answer points out the working of normal scenarios and why you get error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the program that you are starting is trying to listen for connections on a fixed port 3333, and when you start second instance it gives error of "Already Bound". See if there is a way to change that port using some arguments. But I cannot comment on that as you have not provided any source.

But I am just going to explain how things work in normal scenarios

Suppose consumer is listening on port 3333, then it will become the server and accept the connections on that port. And multiple clients can send data on that port to server

**Sample Client Program**

```
BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3333); //3333 is the port on which the    server is listening   
DataOutputStream outToConsumer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromConsumer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));   //Only if consumer sends something in reply
sentence = inFromUser.readLine();   
outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
modifiedSentence = inFromConsumer.readLine();
```

So multiple producers will be clients and send data to consumers who are listening on dedicated ports. Keep in mind multiple consumers will not be able to listen on same socket,
you will have to use **different ports for different consumers**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a connection-oriented protocol (e.g. TCP) the server usually only `listen`s for connections on the advertised port.  When a client `connect`s, the server's `accept` call results in a connection on effectively a random other port number, allowing the main server thread/process to continue listening for new connections on the advertised port.

With a datagram-based protocol (e.g UDP) this isn't an issue because no client maintains a persistent connection.

Either solution could work for you--which one to prefer depends on the nature of the traffic.